# How do I create a text conditional format for 2 or more cells to highlight that text?

Tags: microsoft-excel

For example, let's say I want to highlight the cells that contain the word 'Tool' in cell A4 AND ONLY if the word 'Structure' is in cell B4. What formula would do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a formula along with [**`Conditional Formatting`**](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Use-a-formula-to-apply-conditional-formatting-fed60dfa-1d3f-4e13-9ecb-f1951ff89d7f) to achieve this.

Choose cell `A4`, then click `Conditional Formatting` from the `Home` ribbon. Then select the `Rule Type` of `Use a formula to determine which cells to format`. To do what you desire, use an [`AND`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AND-function-5f19b2e8-e1df-4408-897a-ce285a19e9d9) formula.

This formula will check that all criteria are met before returning `TRUE`. In this case, using `=AND(A4="Tool",B4="Structure")` should do it.

[image]

[image]

Comment: OMG! Thank you Sir so much, been pulling my hair our trying to figure this out and your formula was the answer!

Comment: Great. Please indicate this question has been answered by choosing the check mark to the left. This will show others who are searching that there is an accepted answer for your question.